# Using values from a column for another column

Tags: python, pandas

| County | State | County State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Davis County | NE | Davis County, NE |
| Ark County | UT | Ark County, UT |
| Clay County Party | WI | Clay County Party, WI |

I want to delete the word County and everything that proceeds it in the "County" and "County State column" and then add back the state in the "County State" column

This is what I want

| County | State | County State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Davis | NE | Davis, NE |
| Ark | UT | Ark, UT |
| Clay | WI | Clay, WI |

What I have tried so far:

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace([r' County.*'], '', regex = True, inplace = True)
    if df.State == 'NE': 
                         df['County, State'].replace([r' County.*'], ' ,NE', regex = True, inplace = True)
    elif df.State == 'UT':
                         df['County, State'].replace([r' County.*'], ' ,UT', regex = True, inplace = True)
    elif df.State == 'WI':
                         df['County, State'].replace([r' County.*'], ' ,Wi', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `County` column is cleaned, seems like just string concatonating the two columns would work:

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace([r'\s*?County.*'], '', regex=True, inplace=True)
    df['County State'] = df['County'] + ', ' + df['State']
    return df
```

`county(df)`:

```
  County State County State
0  Davis    NE    Davis, NE
1    Ark    UT      Ark, UT
2   Clay    WI     Clay, WI
```

---

Or match everything up to the comma for the `County State` column:

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace([r'\s*County.*'], '', regex=True, inplace=True)
    df['County State'].replace([r'\s*County[^,]*'], '', regex=True,
                               inplace=True)
    return df
```

`county(df)`:

```
  County State County State
0  Davis    NE    Davis, NE
1    Ark    UT      Ark, UT
2   Clay    WI     Clay, WI
```

---

Regex:
`\s*County[^,]*`

1. `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
2. `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
3. `County` matches the characters `County` literally (case sensitive)
4. Match a single character not present in the list below `[^,]`

   - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   - `,` matches the character `,` literally (case sensitive)